# Coun in two querys

Tags: mysql

I have this query

`SELECT count(*) as open FROM table1 WHERE status='open' UNION SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE status='close'` 
this is the result

```
 open   
 54
 4277
```

but I will like to have this kind of result

```
 status   count(*)
 open         54
 close        4277
```

how the query is should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a single query as

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) 
FROM table1 
WHERE status IN('open' , 'close')
GROUP BY status
```